# How to mock showDialog method

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking, dialog, mockito

I'm unit testing a method calling in the second line this method of the material/dialog class:

```
showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
    ....
   )
```

I get this error in the unit test ->
`'context != null': is not true`
because context is null.
How I can mock the context and inject into it ? or mock directly the method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to convert that to a widget test or even an integration test. See the differences [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing).